# How to replace binary installed via Macports?

Tags: macos, mariadb, macports

I'd like to replace my current MariaDB installation with one compiled with the debug flag. Can I compile a binary and copy/paste over the one installed via Macports or is there something else to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is how I did it. It was a mix of @neverpanic's answer and some more questions from the MariaDB #irc channel:

1. Find the port file for MariaDB: `port file mariadb-10.1`
2. Add debug flags for the build. Under `configure.args-append` add `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` and after the last variant add a new one: `variant debug { configure.optflags -O0 -g3 }`
3. Force a rebuild: `sudo port -sn upgrade --force mariadb-10.1 +debug`
4. Finally do `port contents mariadb-10.1-server` to find the LaunchCtl plist file and add the `--debug` flag after the name of the program.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easiest to edit the MacPorts Portfile, add the flag you need, and re-install. You can locate the Portfile using `port file mariadb-10.1` (if that's the version you are using), edit it and append whatever flags you need to append to `configure.args-append` in the block enclosed by `if {$subport eq $name} { ... }`.

Save the file and run `sudo port -sn upgrade --force mariadb-10.1` to recompile from source, where

- `-s` instructs MacPorts to recompile from source (to avoid downloading a binary that doesn't have the change)
- `-n` instructs MacPorts to leave all dependencies unmodified
- `--force` to rebuild despite mariadb-10.1 already being installed.

Note that any changes to the Portfile will be reverted if you use the rsync method to sync your ports tree (which is the default). If that's not what you want, you can set up a [local portfile repository](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/development.local-repositories.html).